# How modify a python 3 exe to release an update to people?

Tags: python, patch

Sorry in advance for my bad English...

Someone can explain to me how could I change an `exe` written in Python 3 through another `exe`

For example, I create a software with Python3 and `pyQt5`, then I need to release a patch for some bugs or improvements.

How can I do? I think it is possible, a lot of software use `exe` patches which modify the main programs.

Otherwise, I need to modify the `.py` file manually.

And this is quite noising and sometimes impossible for any reason.

Thanks to all!

Henry

Comment: You'd have to re-compile (?) your code if you update. You don't update the current executable, you fix your code and compile a new one.

Comment: yes, i thought, so no way to give a patch or another little program which can do that itself..